# Как расположить картинку максимально вправо

Tags: html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Имеется контейнер(1200px). Как разместить картинку правее, при этом проигнорировав ограничение ширины.

Comment: Правее текста. Скрин выше

Comment: Предположу, что контент блока находится в каком-то контейнере ограниченной ширины. Тогда картинку можно вынести из контейнера и абсолютом спозиционировать как надо. Или вовсе ее добавить фоном

Comment: margin-right с минусовым значением что-ли ? и на контейнер overflow: hidden чтобы нижний скролл не появлялся

Answer (score 1):

Задайте position: relative для контейнера, который имеет ограничение ширины.

```
.container {
    position: relative;
}

img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    right: -100px;
}
```

Если изображение необходимо разместить максимально справа (у правой границы окна браузера), то можно сделать изображение фоном для body

```
body {
    background: url(img.png) top right no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо. Все было куда проще чем думал.

Comment: А можно как-то сделать чтобы картинка была всегда максимально в правой стороне? А не подбирать right

Comment: Можете сделать её фоном для body